# Serving static content in UndertowJaxrsServer

Tags: resteasy, undertow, undertowjaxrsserver

I'm trying to serve static content through a `ResourceHandler` in my Undertow server that has a RestEasy deployment.

```
public class Server {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    UndertowJaxrsServer server = new UndertowJaxrsServer();
    Undertow.Builder serverBuilder = Undertow
            .builder()
            .addHttpListener(8080, "0.0.0.0")
            .setHandler(
                    Handlers.path().addPrefixPath(
                            "/web",
            new ResourceHandler(new PathResourceManager(Paths.get("/some/fixed/path"),100))
                    .setDirectoryListingEnabled(true)
                    .addWelcomeFiles("index.html")));

    ResteasyDeployment deployment = new ResteasyDeployment();
    deployment.setApplicationClass(MyRestApplication.class.getName());
    DeploymentInfo deploymentInfo = server.undertowDeployment(deployment, "/")
            .setClassLoader(Server.class.getClassLoader())
            .setContextPath("/api").setDeploymentName("WS");
    server.deploy(deploymentInfo);
    server.start(serverBuilder); 
  }
}
```

With the above code, only the resteasy deployment works and I get a 404 for the static content (index.html).

Any pointers? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The UndertowJaxrsServer API is a bit tricky. Although you can configure an Undertow.Builder to start the server, the associated handler is replaced by a default PathHandler instance, which is also used to configure the REST application.

So, the proper way of adding more HttpHandlers (such as a ResourceHandler), is by using the UndertowJaxrsServer#addResourcePrefixPath method, to specify extra handlers for your requests.

Here is an example of utilizing the above API to successfully serve static content in addition to REST resources: https://gist.github.com/sermojohn/928ee5f170cd74f0391a348b4a84fba0

Answer (score 1):

This is from one of my toy projects:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    UndertowJaxrsServer server = new UndertowJaxrsServer();

    ResteasyDeployment deployment = new ResteasyDeployment();
    deployment.setApplicationClass(RestEasyConfig.class.getName());
    deployment.setInjectorFactoryClass(CdiInjectorFactory.class.getName());

    DeploymentInfo deploymentInfo = server.undertowDeployment(deployment)
            .setClassLoader(GatewayApi.class.getClassLoader())
            .setContextPath("/api")
            .addFilter(new FilterInfo("TokenFilter", TokenFilter.class))
            .addFilterUrlMapping("TokenFilter", "/*", DispatcherType.REQUEST)
            .addFilterUrlMapping("TokenFilter", "/*", DispatcherType.FORWARD)
            .addListener(Servlets.listener(Listener.class))
            .setDeploymentName("Undertow RestEasy Weld");

    server.deploy(deploymentInfo);
    server.addResourcePrefixPath("/index.htm", resource(new ClassPathResourceManager(GatewayApi.class.getClassLoader()))
                    .addWelcomeFiles("webapp/index.htm"));

    Undertow.Builder undertowBuilder = Undertow.builder()
            .addHttpListener(8080, "0.0.0.0");
    server.start(undertowBuilder);
    log.info(generateLogo());
}
```